# How to add smooth scrolling to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there are already answers to this, but I searched and none is working and I don't know why.

So what I wanted is a smooth scroll to a div by the tag

What I wanted was like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FyAnb/86/)

So I took the js code but on me isn't working at all, the scroll loses his effect at all.

Here is my code:
w
HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3" id="some">
        <a href="#info" id="normal">
            <img src="imgs/product/normal.png" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
</div>

<!-- OTHER CONTENT -->

<div id="info">     
                Go here
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$("#some a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {
  // prevent default anchor click behavior
  e.preventDefault();
  // animate
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
  }, 300, function() {
    // when done, add hash to url
    // (default click behaviour)
    window.location.hash = this.hash;
  });
});
```

Comment: You are including the JQuery library on your page, right?

Comment: Yes I am:
 `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you copy > paste your code but you're missing a quote before the id:

`<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 id="some">`

That could be a solution why it's not working because `$('#some a')` doesn't exist then.

Comment: I didnt copy, it is right on my code, sorry my bad copying the code here. It is like you mencioned.

Answer (score 0):

That is before you have a link inside. BTW look at your console, is there any error messages?

Change your code to:

```
$("#some a").on('click', function(e) {

   // prevent default anchor click behavior
   e.preventDefault();

   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   e.stopPropagation();
   var id = $(this).attr("href");
   // animate
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
     }, 300, function(){

       // when done, add hash to url
       // (default click behaviour)
       window.location.hash = this.hash;
     });

});
```

Comment: It is not working, and there is no error in console.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below code snippet to achieve as you mentioned in post.

```
$(function() {
  $('a').bind('click',function(event){
     var $anchor = $(this);
     $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
     }, 1000);       
      event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

[**check DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JeekOnline/FyAnb/273/)

Comment: No, none of them is working, I think this is relative of some other jquery code I have, because I have onlick events and some hidden divs but is too much code to post here. :s
But thanks anyway.

Comment: Anyways, when I add your code, it stops working the href default scroll. It doesn't smooth scroll neither instant scroll. It just stops working. I know it should work, but can this be caused by other jquery code?
Thanks in advance